# Hair dynamics script is not working

Tags: python, scripting, hair

I found this tutorial about hair in Cycles, the author is applying hair dynamics on a given frame without applying the all modifiers. In fact he is using small script to do the work.

[image: error message]

Here is the link to the video https://youtu.be/yw9DfPjpH1o

Here is what I got so far, the script is crashing http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46749

Comment: Please try resolve the error yourself then if you can't, post a more detailed question relating to what doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a error message that i m getting with running the script http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=115915

Comment: As the error says: "unexpected indent". Select all your code and press Shift Tab to go one indent back.